# How to: Copy files from a source to a destination

Tags: php, directory, copy

I am looking for a way to have files in a source, say:

```
/public_html/source/sourcefiles/
```

and when, in my admin panel, I create a new 'game' (in my case), might be called category, or et cetera in other projects, copy those source files into a directory such as:

```
/public_html/games/gamename/sourcefiles_copied_here/
```

Is there a way to do this?

If it is possible, I'd also need a way to delete them when the game/category is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

---

The php `copy` function is useful for copying files from a source, into a new directory.

It is used like this:

`copy(sourcedir, destdir);`

Keep in mind that files that already exist in the destination directory with the same name as the files being copied WILL be overwritten.

To move a file, use the `rename` function.